# Why are variables declared after root automatically added to UI in TornadoFx?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have stumbled upon a behaviour in TornadoFx that doesn't seem to be mentioned anywhere (I have searched a lot) and that I'm wondering about.

If I define a view like this with the TornadoFx builders for the labels:

```
class ExampleView: View() {

    override
    val root = vbox{ label("first label") }

    val secondLabel = label("second label")
}
```

The result is:

[image]

That is, the mere definition of `secondLabel` automatically adds it to the `root`of the scene.

However, if I place this definition BEFORE the definition of `root`...

```
class ExampleView: View() {

    val secondLabel = Label("second label")

    override
    val root = vbox{ label("first label") }
}
```

... or if I use the JavaFx `Label`class instead of the TornadoFx builder ...

```
class ExampleView: View() {

    override
    val root = vbox{ label("first label") }

    val secondLabel = Label("second label")
}
```

... then it works as I expect:

[image]

Of course, I can simply define all variables in the view before I define the `root`element but I'm still curious why this behaviour exists; perhaps I am missing some general design rule or setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builders in TornadoFX automatically attach themselves to the current parent in the scope they are called in. Therefore, if you call a builder function on the View itself, the generated ui component is automatically added to the root of that View. That's what you're seeing.

If you really have a valid use case for creating a ui component outside of the hierarchy it should be housed in, you shouldn't call a builder function, but instead instantiate the element with it's constructor, like you did with `Label()`. However, the use cases for such behavior are slim to none.

Best practice is to store value properties in the view or a view model and bind the property to the ui element using the builders. You then manipulate the value property when needed, and the change will automatically update in the ui. Therefore, you very very seldom have a need to access a specific ui element at a later stage. Example:

```
val myProperty = SimpleStringProperty("Hello world")

override val root = hbox {
    label(myProperty)
}
```

When you want to change the label value, you just update the property. (The property should be in an injected view model in a real world application).

If you really need to have a reference to the ui element, you should declare the ui property first, then assign to it when you actually build the ui element. Define the ui property using the `singleAssign()` delegate to make sure you only assign to it once.

```
var myLabel: Label by singleAssign()

override val root = hbox {
    label("My label) {
        myLabel = this
    }
}
```

I want to stress again that this is very rarely needed, and if you feel you need it you should look to restructure your ui code to be more data driven.

Another technique to avoid storing references to ui elements is to leverage the EventBus to listen for events. There are plenty of examples of this out there.

Comment: Thanks for answering and explaining! My use case is similar to the example at https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part1/11_Editing_Models_and_Validation.html. If no model is chosen (maybe the left table is empty) then I want the right part to show some placeholder before the actual view of the model in question is shown. But maybe this should not be done by programmatically exchanging a placeholder element for the actual content in the UI once a data model (Person in this case) is chosen?

Comment: That's easy :) The ViewModel has an `empty` property, so you can bind the visibility of the form to the state of the viewmodel. For example, `form { hiddenWhen(viewModel.empty) }`. Likewise, you can show the placeholder with `visibleWhen(viewModel.empty)`